# TeamBuild - Is it possible to choose what projects to compile at build-time?

Tags: tfs, build, build-automation

I am automating my build process using TeamFoundation and I need to choose what projects to compile according to the .proj file from the build. Here is the full scenario:

I have a .proj file which uses a .sln file in order to compile a solution which contains 2 websites. The .sln file is configured to compile both websites in Release configuration.

My goal is to compile only 1 website per build type, namely I want the BuildType1 to compile website 1 and BuildType2 to compile the website 2.

Is is possible to "modify" the .sln in such a way that I can unmark one of the websites to compile? Since it is an automated process, I can't change the .sln manually every time I want to compile only one website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the SolutionToBuild section in the TFSBuild.proj file.

```
<SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/path/MySolution.sln">
   <Targets>MyCustomTarget1;MyCustomTarget2</Targets>
   <Properties> Configuration=Release</Properties>
</SolutionToBuild>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, leppie.
Let me see if I got what you said, If I make a custom target to each project I don't want to compile, those targets will overrite the default targets and if I simply let them empty it will skip the compilation of the project?
If so, how can I link a target with a project? I mean, Lets say I have 50 projects in my solution, I want to skip the compilation of one of them, can I do it modyfing only the TFSBUILD.proj file, since I can't change the .csproj of each project?

Comment: You can create a new config at solution level (the IDE will ask if you want to create the config for the projects too). Note: You will only modify the Configuration part in the .proj, so the rest can be easily tested on the client side.

Comment: Hmm, I got it..
I think the required changes in the solution are simple enought to ask the development team do it, I don't think they will complain about it.
Thanks leppie!

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways you can control the build:

- create a separate Build Type in your Team Explorer. This will have its own completely independent TFSBuild.proj file, so it can build the same code-base in a completely different way. Set the SolutionToBuild up to build just what you want (as described in the accepted answer).
- Use one Build Type, and set its TFSBuild.proj up to use a property to control what is built (this requires more in depth understanding od MSBuild scripts). In the Queue New Build dialog you can then use the /p: command line flag to set the property as you need it. e.g. "/p:IncrementalGet=false;IncrementalBuild=false;ForceGet=true" will force a normally incremental build to do a full rebuild. This is useful for occasoinal situations, but not a good idea for day to day builds as you have to set the parameters by hand every time.